# Bootstrap Month Picker not work correctly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap monthpicker:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months",
    minViewMode: "months"
});

<div class='input-group date' id='datepicker'> 
   <input type='text' class="form-control" readonly /> 
      <span class="input-group-addon"> 
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 
       </span>
    </div>
```

[image]

Like this picture, I chose Apr but class active add to February, and same for another month, it's always minus 2 month.

Comment: Can you provide your code printing the date?

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

Reference here: [DateTime Picker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

For version 1.2.0 and newer, viewMode has changed to startView, so use:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    startView: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

See Reference here: [DateTime Picker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#startdate)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work i believe.

```
$('#datepicker')
 .datetimepicker(pickerOptsGeneral)
 .on('changeDate', function(ev){
     var oldDate = new Date(ev.date);
     var newDate = new Date();
     newDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + 60);
     newdate.datetimepicker('update');
});
```

Basically get the old date, assign to variable, set second variable to old date + 60 days. The reaosn its 2 months early might be to do with the localisation settings on your server